# Does $|a_n-a|\leq 2\epsilon$ $\forall \epsilon>0$ and $\forall n \geq n_\epsilon$ imply $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n=a$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Consider a sequence of real numbers $\{a_n\}_n$ and a real number $a$. Suppose I show that $|a_n-a|\leq 2\epsilon$ $\forall \epsilon>0$ and $\forall n \geq n_\epsilon$ with $n,n_{\epsilon} \in \mathbb{N}$. Does it mean that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n=a$?

What confuses me is the fact that I show $|a_n-a|\leq 2\epsilon$ $\forall \epsilon$ and not $|a_n-a|\leq \epsilon$ $\forall \epsilon$.

Comment: If I give you an $\epsilon>0$ and ask you to find an $n_{\epsilon}$ such that $n\ge n_{\epsilon}\implies|a_n-a|<\epsilon$, you can take $\epsilon^{\prime}=\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and find a corresponding $n_{\epsilon'}$, and then $n\ge n_{ \epsilon'}\implies|a_n-a|\le2\epsilon^{\prime}=\epsilon$.  This shows that $a_n\to a$.

Comment: The assertion that $|a_n-a|\leq 2\epsilon$ $\forall \epsilon>0$ and $\forall n \geq n_\epsilon$ with $n,n_{\epsilon} \in \mathbb{N}$, might be one of the most mangled ways there is, of stating a limit. As if one *wanted* to err...